# Arch: All warnings treated as errors?

Tags: arch-linux, make

I'm trying to `make` a downloaded driver, [xf86-video-armsoc](https://github.com/endlessm/xf86-video-armsoc), on Arch Linux. However, the configuration of `make` prevents me from compiling the driver because it treats all compiler warnings as errors. Is there any way I can disable this?

I've read through the errors thrown, and they all look like warnings. They're things like `storage of 's' isn't known`, `implicit declaration of function`, `nested extern declaration` and `unused variable`, which all sound like they can be ignored.

Comment: Usually warning as error is turned on with `-Werror`. grep for it and remove everywhere you will find this.

Comment: Thanks, is there anywhere specific I should be trying to find it? Will this be in the `src` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warnings as errors are usually result of `-Werror` passed somewhere to the compiler. It can be intentional enforcement from developer to see how much mistakes are still there and being left only because it's still in development, or intentional enforcement in mission critical software.

Anyway, you need to find out where `-Werror` is. `grep` is a nice tool for that: just recursively grep for whole word (leading dash does not matter): `grep -lr Werror .`, while residing in drivers source code directory.

Then you can remove the switch from each file with simple `sed -i 's@-Werror@@g' file`.

Looking in https://github.com/endlessm/xf86-video-armsoc/blob/master/src/Makefile.am I see an explicit `-Werror` set in ERROR_CFLAGS, so developer decided to catch some non fatal warnings too.

Unfortunately `-Werror` is useless and annoying when building release software, because compilers widely vary. Simple things like implicit function declarations and incompatible pointers / storage size mismatches do require attention, but it's a developer task to make their code match to common and accepted standards.

Comment: Perfect answer, really goddamn helpful. Thank you siblynx!